# SQLlite vs String-array for storing lots of small paragraphs?

Tags: android, sqlite, text, arrays

I need to have about 120 different paragraphs of text stored somewhere in my app, so that I can display some of those paragraphs to the user.

Since those paragraphs are groups of 12 I was thinking of creating 12 different string-arrays in my values/strings.xml file, so that I can access them easily, without much hassle.

What is the best practice to do so? Do i lose anything if I chose the one way instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they never change at runtime, then sticking them in string resources is by far the easier option.

Comment: @Alex: I'd take this approach to for static strings, especially if at some point you're going to support more than one language.

Comment: Good point there. Idd the values are never going to change, so yeah the string-array does sound more appealing